# how to get android and ios devices id in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

hello everyone i am try to get android unique device id but i try all packages no any packages work for me so please anyone help me how to get device id in flutter . i also try firebase id but it’s didn’t work. i need sample or examples for how i get device id i read many answers from stack overflow but no any solution .

i try this package :

- device_info
- device_info_plus

i need device id for user can use my app without log in they get his data by his device .

i need help for get device if android and ios both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://pub.dev/packages/android_id/install

A Flutter plugin for getting the Android ID. Only for Android.

```
android_id: ^0.1.3+1
```

```
String? androidId = await const AndroidId().getId();
```

iOS

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
iOSId = iosInfo.identifierForVendor;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Android's unique device id"?  There is no such thing, for security and privacy reasons.  See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids  for more info.  On Android you can get a random id for a particular device, but if your app is ever uninstalled, or if the device is factory reset, you will get a new id next time you ask for it.

Comment: It is the same on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I you [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) for getting android and ios unique device no.

For android it's `androidNo` but for the ios devices there's `identifierForVendor`.

```
/// Will return the Device unique no.
Future<String?> getDeviceNo() async {

  /// [DeviceNo]
  late final String? deviceNo;

  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  // If the application if running on [Android] platform.
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    deviceNo = androidDeviceInfo.id;
  } else {
    // If the application if running on [IOS] platform.
    IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    deviceNo = iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor;
  }

  return deviceNo;
}
```